# Is long-lived Gmail auth a security risk on a travel laptop?

Tags: security, gmail

I have a throwaway travel laptop with an encrypted drive and secure boot enabled (windows 10).

Gmail's default behavior seems to be to leave me logged in for days at a time.

If I lose my laptop, can an attacker access my logged-in gmail session if they don't know the user PIN for my windows log on?

I would expect the answer to be "no", but wondering if I need to shorten my gmail auth to timeout more aggressively.

Comment: Alternate process: Open Gmail, go to your avatar pic at upper right, click on it, and log off. Then clear the cache and cookies in the browser you use for Gmail, and purge the Windows pagefile per https://zillowtech.com/delete-pagefile-sys-windows-10.html . Problem solved.